# HQL generate wrong query with complex insert

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I need to insert a huge amount of data in a table that is in FK with another one that has a two big fields in Eager.

The HQL query is:

```
insert into DeviceAuthorizationEntry (id, osc, moduleName, delegateModule, functionName, groupName, owner) 
   select concat(item0.id.uuid, '1413971469473'),  item0.osc, 'aaaaaaaa',
      'devices', 'view_devices', 'administrator', item0 
   from device.model.Device as item0 
   where item0.osc IN (:oscNameList0) 
   and item0.nodeTypeDefinition.QN IN (:nodeTypesList0) 
   and not exists (select 1 from device.model.DeviceAuthorizationEntry as auth 
                 where auth.moduleName != 'aaaaaaa' 
                       and auth.delegateModule != 'devices' 
                       and auth.functionName != 'view_devices' 
                       and auth.groupName != 'administrator' 
                       and auth.owner != item0 )
```

But the one executed on Oracle is:

```
INSERT
INTO DeviceAuthorizationEntry
  (
    id,
    osc,
    moduleName,
    delegateModule,
    functionName,
    groupName,
    owner_uuid
  )
SELECT device0_.uuid
  ||'1413965664136' AS col_0_0_,
  device0_.osc      AS col_1_0_,
  'aaaaaaaa'    AS col_2_0_,
  'devices'         AS col_3_0_,
  'view_devices'    AS col_4_0_,
  'administrator'   AS col_5_0_,
  device0_.uuid     AS col_6_0_
FROM dem_device device0_,
  cor_noddef nodetypede1_
WHERE device0_.uuid_ndtypedef=nodetypede1_.uuid
AND 1                        =1
AND (device0_.osc           IN (? , ?))
AND (nodetypede1_.QN        IN (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?))
AND NOT (EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM DeviceAuthorizationEntry deviceauth2_
  WHERE deviceauth2_.moduleName  <>'aaaaaaaa'
  AND deviceauth2_.delegateModule<>'devices'
  AND deviceauth2_.functionName  <>'view_devices'
  AND deviceauth2_.groupName     <>'administrator'
  AND deviceauth2_.owner_uuid    <>uuid
  ))
```

As you can see in the last "and" of the exists subquery, hibernate does not precede the "uuid" field with the alias "device0_".

Hibernate supports the insert into select as you can see here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e2610

I don't know where I'm wrong.

Comment: Is `uuid` really ambiguous here ?

Comment: yes, as you can see from the HQL query here hibernate should put the alias of "item0" before "uuid".

Comment: I'm not very familiar with HQL so pardon me if I don't use the right vocabulary here, but is it legal to use `item0` both as a column name and as a table alias? `select ...., item0 from ... as item0`

Comment: There is a bug in Hibernate: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1657  Maybe it's your case

Comment: Yes, this bug signals my problem. I tried the suggested workaround but for me didn't work. SO I need to find another way to do the same query.